# Pointing Sub domain of one website to sub folder of another website

Tags: .htaccess, virtualhost, subdomain, xampp

I have a domain **example.com** pointing to Linux AWS.
I also have **demo.example.com** which i need to point to /htdocs/**c5** of **example2.com** on Windows Server running XAMPP.

**My Findings**
Used A record of demo.example.com point to example2.com
Changed the *httpd.conf* on Windows Server to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/c5"
    ServerName demo.example.in 
</VirtualHost>
```

**Problem**
If i do so all my requests are forwarded to /htdocs/c5.
But i need only if request from demo.example.com comes it need to be forwarded to /htdoc/c5 & if i access example2.com it should display /htdocs

**Provided**
URL masking: i mean example2.com should be displayed in addressbar instead of example.com/c5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a second virtual host, not replace the original. Make one for example.com and one for demo.example.com.